# toolStripButton Has no Definition for 'Show' & 'Hide'? (c#)

Tags: c#, hide, show, definition, toolstripbutton

So before I go to my problem I have some things to point out.
-They are in the same Form
-Regular Buttons work
-This is being activated on the press of a button
So my error is `'ToolStripButton' does not contain a definition for 'Show' and no extension method 'Show' accepting a first arguement of type 'ToolStripButton' could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference)`
Then again I am really nooby at C# and I am probably missing a c# using system thing but I have no idea what. here are all my usings

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
```

ok and finally here is a gyazo of my error
https://gyazo.com/bc25c1c9430c46a24bbf4066ad5d1c62
Thanks all appreciated don't hate I am starting off with c# training !!!
PS. I tried to make my tags as specific as possible, don't hate on that either please :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems based on your description you are trying to click a regular button in order to either make a toolstrip button visible, or make a toolstrip menu open.

Can you clarify that? If you are using show to have the toolstrip button visible, have you tried looking up the toolstrip button class for its different commands? It seems you need to use .visible = true to "show it" if I am understanding your question.

.enabled could be another option if you want it shown but clickable/not clickable.

Hope this helps or allows you to clarify.

Comment: I am trying to hide a button to reveal another button, and your tips helped me and successfully worked. Thanks!